# What is the Distinction between DSCOVR's "engines" and "thrusters"?

Tags: artificial-satellite, propulsion, station-keeping, dscovr

I am reading this [article](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/d/dscovr) about DSCOVR which links (ref 16) to this: [*DSCOVR: Mission Success for Moog Engines Over a Decade Later*](http://spaceref.com/news/viewpr.html?pid=45046)
, about the recertification by MOOG of the MONARC 5N monopropellant engines and thruster valves.

When I read these two, I don't understand - are there *both* engines *and* thrusters? Could someone explain the distinction - and possibly locate a clear diagram with DSCOVRs various propulsion elements used for the mid-course correction (MCC), Lissajous orbit insertion (LOI), and all station-keeping tasks? Here is a sample paragraph from [here](http://spaceref.com/news/viewpr.html?pid=45046):

> *"The 5N engines will be used for attitude control and minor adjustments to maintain the satellite’s Lagrange-1 (L-1) orbit one million miles from Earth; DSCOVR is the nation’s first operational spacecraft in deep space. DSCOVR has two key burns: Mid-Course Correction (MCC) and Lissajous Orbit Insertion (LOI). The thrusters will be used to perform the MCC for 50 minutes and LOI for 5.3 hours. After reaching L-1, DSCOVR will perform station-keeping and momentum unloading with the thrusters."*

Comment: Here is a [follow-up](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/14274/12102) question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the [terms are being used interchangeably](http://spaceflight101.com/dscovr/). DISCOVR has one type of engine, i.e. the MOOG Monarc 5N thruster.

> DSCOVR is equipped with ten thrusters that can be used for spacecraft attitude control as well as translational maneuvers that are required for mid-course corrections and orbital adjustment maneuvers around L1. Ten thrusters are fed from a pressurized Hydrazine tank, making use of the catalytic decomposition of hydrazine over a metallic catalyst bed to create a hot gas that generates thrust. With a total propellant mass of 145 Kilograms, the mission has a total delta-v budget of 600m/s which is sufficient for the transfer to L1, orbital adjustment maneuvers and regular reaction wheel momentum dumps.

A more common usage is to use the term "engines" for large, main propulsion units, and "thrusters" for small units that do maneuvering and attitude control.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! For the part: "*...and possibly locate a clear diagram...*" I'll break it out as a separate question.

Comment: Here is the [follow-up](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/14274/12102) question