# Why not add tracking features to upper stages? Has something like this ever been proposed?

Tags: debris, tracking, visibility-of-spacecraft

The identity of the object that will hit the Moon in early March is still uncertain. Some of the story is in [Why did we think that the object was gonna hit the Moon March 4th 2022? Who's been tracking and predicting it so closely?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57964/12102) and more can be found in this (temporary?) Project Pluto post [Corrected identification of object about to hit the moon](https://www.projectpluto.com/temp/correct.htm#reentry)

It could have been an asteroid, was then assigned to the DSCOVR mission upper stage, and is now currently assigned to China's Chang'e-5 T1 though apparently there's some pushback from China as well as based on some info from 18SPCS.

- Space.com [China says moonbound rocket stage was not from 2014 lunar mission: report](https://www.space.com/china-denies-moonbound-rocket-stage)
- Space.com [Moon mystery: Who launched the rocket that will slam into the lunar far side?](https://www.space.com/moonbound-rocket-stage-china-denial-mystery)
- The Verge [China casts doubt on origin of rocket debris about to slam into the Moon](https://www.theverge.com/2022/2/22/22945801/china-change-5-t1-rocket-debris-moon-collision-update)

---

**Question:** Why not add tracking features to upper stages? Has something like this ever been proposed?

Since radar return signal strength drops as $1/r^4$ there needs to be other means to help in tracking and identification.

Perhaps the following will be helpful, as their signals drop as only $1/r^2$ for things near 1 AU

1. a little solar powered beacon gizmos that beep once per second on a specific frequency,
2. get some special paint with a unique reflection spectrum, say filled with some iridescent particles that use thin film interference to impose a fingerprint on the reflected sunlight's spectrum. That way any telescope that can pick them up can make a low-dispersion spectral analysis (a simple grating or GRISM somewhere in the optical path in front of the camera, no need for using an external spectrograph.

See:

- [How were "microshutters" or other multiplexed or multi-object techniques first used in Astronomical spectroscopy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38860/7982)
- [this answer to *What equipment do I need to measure the spectrum of a star?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33335/7982)

> [image]
>
> **above:** from [here](http://www.fieldtestedsystems.com/poster/)
>
> See the FieldTestedSystems' YouTube video *How to capture star spectra in your backyard*

Comment: companion question [Project Pluto: "Should high-flying space junk be better tracked? Perhaps by an 'official' agency of some sort?" What would it take to implement?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58420/12102)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such features have been added to an upper stage once at least, albeit for a very specialized purpose.

The RM-81 Agena

> was an American rocket upper stage and satellite bus which was developed by Lockheed Corporation initially for the canceled WS-117L reconnaissance satellite program...[and] was later used as an upper stage, and an integrated component, for several programs, including Corona reconnaissance satellites and *the Agena Target Vehicle used to demonstrate rendezvous and docking during Project Gemini*.

(emphasis mine)

It was the latter (italicized) special use that involved the installation of "tracking features" on the upper stage.

> Also added were strobe lights and an L-band radar transponder to aid in rendezvous operations.

Sources:

- Wikipedia Agena article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RM-81_Agena
- Drew Ex Machina Gemini 9 article https://www.drewexmachina.com/2016/06/06/the-angry-alligator-the-snake-the-mission-of-gemini-9/